# Why do I get 404 error with set command in Nginx

Tags: nginx

Recently I added a trim action to remove sensitive data in access log for Nginx, however, by adding this, I am seeing 404 errors that never happened before.

New configuration:

```
  location / {
    set $temp $request;

    if ( $temp ~ (.*)(lat|lng)=(-?\d+\.[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?)\d*(.*)(lat|lng)=(-?\d+\.[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?)\d*(.*) ) {
      set $temp $1$4$7;
    }


    try_files $temp @gunicorn;
  }

  location @gunicorn {
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    add_header        X-UA-Compatible 'chrome=IE8';
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header  X-Request-Start 't=$start_time';
    proxy_set_header  X-Queue-Start   't=$start_time';
    proxy_intercept_errors on;

    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;

    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto 'https';
  }
```

If I visit url `/order/US/xxxxxx`, everything's fine, but if I visit url like `/order/US/xxxxx?lat=1.23&lng=2.34`, I get a 404 error. I also tried visit url without Nginx directly to application, it's fine.

What actually went wrong here?

Comment: See [this page](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/). You could try moving the `set` statement and `if` block to be outside of any `location` block.

Comment: @RichardSmith you are just brilliant! It works!

Comment: @RichardSmith almost forgot to ask why do I have to move it out of location. I don't understand why set command can change uri.

Comment: The linked document only relates to `if` statements within a `location` block.